# Exporting Bitcoin settings to bitcoin.conf?

Tags: security, bitcoin.conf

How do I Export/dump the settings of bitcoin into a .conf file?
I know I can review some of them via bitcoin-qt GUI.

I'm not interested in the GUI settings like font, etc.
I'm interested in exporting ALL the settings eg.

```
  prune=1000
  server=1
  datadir=/myAwsumDir 
  addnode=127.0.0.1:18442
  fallbackfee=0.00001
  etc.
```

I want a text file of all the settings.

FYI: I have already used this very good tool to generate a .conf file
[Bitcoin Core Config Generator](https://jlopp.github.io/bitcoin-core-config-generator/)

but it's only a generator. It doesn't query the actual current settings.

Perhaps Bitcoin doesn't allow exporting of settings? If not why not? Are there security concerns about exporting .conf settings? What are they?

Comment: AFAIK when you run bitcoind it will use your bitcoin.conf in the default directory if you have one. Typically `.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf` in your users home folder. Otherwise if you run bitcoind with arguments that will override things you've set in bitcoin.conf. One way to get your current settings is to just look at what is in your bitcoin.conf. 

Potential security concerns are you can set the rpcpassword in the conf file along with other potential sensitive information.

Comment: Yes, this is all true but not what I'm looking for.  bitcoin.conf often does not provide a complete listing of all the settings.

Comment: which setting specifically are you trying to figure out? (if not understood by looking at the bitcoin.conf).

Comment: no one setting in particular.  I want to know what ALL the settings are.  The bitcoin.conf doesn't list ALL settings.

Comment: You want to know all the default values that aren't specified?
You can look up what the default values are if they are not set in the bitcoin.conf.